# Adding an instance of subtype of abstract class in typescript

Tags: typescript, abstraction

I was wondering how would one implement the example below. I am trying to abstract away some core functionality of House. I ran into this situation.

Let's say there is an abstract Animal class extended as shown below

```js
abstract class Animal{
    constructor(age:number){
        this.age = age;
    }
    age:number;
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    constructor(age:number){
        super(age);
    }
    bark(){
        console.log("Bark");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal{
    constructor(age:number){
        super(age);
    }
    meow(){
        console.log("Meow");
    }
}
```

The whole point is to make this a base class of the application and many classes of different animal houses extend this and its core functions

```
abstract class House{
    animals:Animal[];

    addAnimal(humanAge:number){
        const animalAge = humanAge/7;
        // How to add an animal here kind of like animals.push(new Animal(animalAge));
    }
}

class DogHouse extends House{
    doSomethingElseHERE(){
       console.log("Something else")
    }
}

new DogHouse().addAnimal(23); //What would be a viable solution to make this work seamlessly in every animal house like this
```

So what would be a good implementation for add function in the abstract class **House**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `House` generic so instead of `Animal` the element type can be any type of animal in derived classes. Also if you need to create an element in the base class you can pass in the constructor of the specific animal as a parameter to the base class:

```
abstract class House<T extends Animal>{
    animals: T[];
    constructor(private elementCtor: new (age: number) => T) {

    }

    addAnimal(humanAge: number) {
        const animalAge = humanAge / 7;
        this.animals.push(new this.elementCtor(animalAge));
    }
}

class DogHouse extends House<Dog> {
    constructor() {
        super(Dog)
    }
    doSomethingElseHERE() {
        console.log("Something else")
    }
}
```

Another option is to create an abstract method in `House`:

```
abstract class House{
    animals: Animal[];
    constructor() {

    }
    abstract createAnimal(age: number): Animal
    addAnimal(humanAge: number) {
        const animalAge = humanAge / 7;
        this.animals.push(this.createAnimal(animalAge));
    }
}

class DogHouse extends House {
    createAnimal(age: number): Animal {
        return new Dog(age);
    }
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    doSomethingElseHERE() {
        console.log("Something else")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same solutions but in the first case I ended up with many types in real world scenario as I needed a store which holds let's say not only animals but also humans and some other stuff. What is the general thought. How many type arguments are considered "bad" in general?

Comment: @NejdiKroi I would not go above 3/4 if the user actually has to specify them (they are not inferred).